# Add a component to another component React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello I am trying to add a new component called ListItem whenewher I enter the text to the input and press "Add" button.

```
    var Input = React.createClass({

    addListItem: function(){
    console.log(this.refs.input.value);
    <ListItem>{this.refs.input.value}</ListItem>

    },
        render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                  <input ref="input" type="text"/>
                  <button onClick={this.addListItem}>Add</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var ListItem = React.createClass({

        render: function(){
            return (
                <li class="listItem">
                  {this.props.value}
                </li>
            );          
        }
    });

ReactDOM.render(<Input/>, container);
```

The problem is that the component does are not being created, I have also tried just to add some text in the li element, when i thought that the props are not getting passed, but that was not the issue.

What am I not understanding here ?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain items state and use it to render the ListItem's:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        items: []
    };
},
addListItem: function(){
    var items = this.state.items;
    items.push(this.refs.input.value);
    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <input ref="input" type="text"/>
            <button onClick={this.addListItem}>Add</button>
            {this.getItems()}
        </div>
    );
},
getItems: function(){
    return this.state.items.map(function (i) {
        return <ListItem>{i}</ListItem>

    });
 }
});
```

Comment: This gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Input = React.createClass({
getInitialState(){
    return {
        list :[]
    }
},
addListItem: function(){
    let array = this.state.list;
     array.push({value:this.refs.input.value});
    this.setState({list: array});

},
render: function(){
    let list = this.state.list;
    console.log(list)
    let item = list&&list.map((d,i)=>{
            return (
                <ListItem key={i}>{d.value}</ListItem>
            );
        });
    return (
        <div>
            <input ref="input" type="text"/>
            <button onClick={this.addListItem}>Add</button>
            <ul>
                {item}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({

render: function(){
    return (
        <li>
            {this.props.children}
        </li>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Please provide information about what is happening here. If you tell people what to do, they might have their problem fixed. If you tell people WHY you do that, they might learn something.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13226774)